# How to cut / paste only certain features from a vector layer onto a new vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features, select, vector-layer

I have a large vector layer in QGIS (180,000 features) and I would like to select only certain features (based on their area) then cut and paste them onto a new vector layer. Essentially I want to separate the largest features from the rest of the vector layer so I can work with them independently.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Go to Layer -> Filter -> PolyArea greater than...